# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, servicepointmanager

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2, in which I'm consuming secure API (e.g.https://google.com) from non-secure portal.
But I am getting below error while requesting API :

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

I have already tried with `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` , `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`, `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` etc. but it didn't work.

When i am using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`, then I'm getting error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not supported"

Sample code(s) which i have already tried ::

1.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls   |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

2.

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
        (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    { // somecode }
}
```

3.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
        (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
        {
            return true;
        },
        SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12   |
                       SslProtocols.Tls11   |
                       SslProtocols.Tls     |
                       SslProtocols.Ssl3    |
                       SslProtocols.Ssl2    |
                       SslProtocols.Default |
                       SslProtocols.None
};
```

Comment: The message of exception asked you to look into InnerException. Have you tried that? What inside? (Suggest that root cause inside)

Comment: The error is regarding SSL.

Comment: Error is ::  System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)

Comment: And the solution ::                 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
 is working in windows but not in ubuntu

Comment: Have you ever managed to fix this? I have the same problem. I have tried everything I could found and nothing worked.

Comment: I have deployed my website with SSL then its working properly.